# Iframe Height in the Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, google-chrome, iframe

I have an iFrame inside my .aspx page that redirect to a external page, that are outside of my solution.

The problem that I got is in the Google Chrome, the Height of the iFrame seems change the Height of the .aspx page. This occurs just on the Google Chrome.

```
<iframe runat="server" id="ifTest" name="ifTest" frameborder="0" height="790px"
width="960px" class="iframeTest" style="position:inherit;"></iframe>
```

The CSS class iframeTest is outside of my solution, how I said, my iframe show a page that are outside of my solution.

For exemple, this is a sample of the iframe in the code-behind to show a page that are outside of my solution.

```
this.ifTest.Attributes["src"] = "the_page_link_that_i_want";
```

My problem is just the iframe Height in the Google Chrome, because the page in Google Chrome shows a big white space after the footer.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `px` in the `width` and `height` attributes in the iframe.

E.g.

```
<iframe runat="server" id="ifTest" name="ifTest" frameborder="0" height="790"
width="960" class="iframeTest" style="position:inherit;"></iframe>
```

AND/OR

add an extra style :

```
iframe{ width:960px; height:790px;}
```

*Let me know if this helps, otherwise I can investigate more...is there some link I can have a look at? Or a JSfiddle link?

Comment: Well, I found the solution. I just put the iframe inside ANOTHER div. Seems strange because without this div, in all the browsers works fine. DIV STYLE OVERFLOW HIDDEN